# Every Class in Django must have the function __init__()?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and understand that the `__init__()` function is used to construct object from certain class. However,I also see some class code without a `__init__()` class function, so my question is that is the `__init__()` function really necessary for all class? And you might also correct me if there is anything wrong with my understanding of this function. Thank you.

Comment: no it is not. If you dont specify one, it would use a default `__init__()` function. Just try it out yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [Class objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

The [`__init__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) function is called when the object is created:

```
>>> class MyBoringClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Being initialised!'

>>> b = MyBoringClass()
Being initialised!
```

It can also accept parameters:

```
>>> class MyInterestingClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print 'Initialised as {}'.format(name)
        self.name = name

>>> i = MyInterestingClass('Mona')
Initialised as Mona
>>> i.name 
Mona
```

If you don't need it, then don't use it.

By the way, Django is a web framework written in Python - `__init()__` comes from Python.